# Find whether an element of a list exists in another string

Tags: python

I Would like to check if any one of delimiters present in list exists in the string c. If exists, the string should be split based on delimiter and right part of delimiter should be result.

I have launched an EC2 instance and executed below python code on it.

```
d=['[', ']', '(', ')', ',', '|', ' ']
c='csvfile|1234'
matching = [i for i in d if i in c]

if matching:
        v=c.split(i)[1]
        print(int(v))
else:
        print 'doesn\'t exists'
```

expected result: `1234`
actual result:

```
$python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    v=c.split(i)[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: What if there are multiple delimiters in the string?

Comment: @Austin my requirement is, there shall be only a delimiter in the string.

Comment: So what will be the output in case there are multiple delimiters present in the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `next` on a generator to find index of the first symbol and slice the string:

```
d = ['[', ']', '(', ')', ',', '|', ' ']
c = 'csvfile|1234'

try:
    indx = next(i for i, x in enumerate(c) if x in d)
    print(c[indx+1:])
except StopIteration:
    print("does not exist")

# 1234
```

This handles cases where there are multiple delimiters too. For eg: `'csvfile|12,3[4'` still gives `12,3[4`.

Answer (score 0):

If `i` is defined on line 6, it's probably not equal to `'|'`. `i` is only usefully defined inside of the list comprehension on line 3. By line 6, you shouldn't expect it to have a useful value.

Answer (score 0):

i is outside the loop so when you try to index by it, it is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you checking on `i` which is not present in the context? Well `i` is present but it is pointing to last character in the string and not the delimiter which you can you to split on while matching is the list of delimiters present in the string. So assuming there is only one delimiter then on index 0 we have the required delimiter which you can use to split the string on

```
d=['[', ']', '(', ')', ',', '|', ' ']
c='csvfile|1234'
matching = [i for i in d if i in c]

if matching:
        v=c.split(matching[0])[1]
        print(int(v))
else:
        print 'doesn\'t exists'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
d = ['[', ']', '(', ')', ',', '|', ' ']
c = 'csvfile|1234'

matching = [i for i in d if i in c]

if matching:
    v = c.split(matching[0])[1]
    print(int(v))
else:
    print("doesn't exist")
```

Output:

```
1234
```

Replace `i` with `matching[0]`. This will get the first element in `matching` instead of `i`, which shouldn't even be defined in that scope.

Also, I'm not sure if you are using Python 2 or 3, because you used both the `print` function and statement. I changed both `print`s to Python 3, so change it back if needed

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import re
d=['[', ']', '(', ')', ',', '|', ' ']
c='csvfile|1234'
re.split('|'.join(d), c)[-1]
```

Output:

```
'1234'
```

Answer (score 0):

try the below written code this may help you:

```
# d is the list of delimiter
d=['[', ']', '(', ')', ',', '|', ' ']
# c here is string
c='csvfile]1234'

for i in d:
    if i in c:
        print i, " in ", c   # tells us the delimiter is present in the string
        # next line gives us the right part to our delimiter of string 
        print 'this is the right part of splited string : ',c.split(i)[1]
        print ''      # a next blank line
    else:
        print i, "not in ", c   # tell us that the symbol is not in string
        print ''                # a next blank line
```